# I tried to make a Python clock , but i can't make it to loop

Tags: python, clock

I tried to make a Clock in Python , but I cannot to make it loop with the "for loop" , How can I make it work, so it will loop the end ASCII?

```
text = " The Date and Time Is : "
```

Here I instructed python to get the local time with the `datetime` Module

```
import datetime 
x = datetime.datetime.now()
Year = (x.strftime("%Y"))




import datetime 
x = datetime.datetime.now()
Month = (x.strftime("%B"))




import datetime 
x = datetime.datetime.now()


Day = (x.strftime("%A"))


NumDay = (x.strftime ("%d"))




import datetime 
x = datetime.datetime.now()
Time = (x.strftime("%X"))

Pm = (x.strftime("%p"))

full_time = Time+ " " +Pm






now = "Today is : " + str(Day) + " , " + str(NumDay) + " " + str(Month) + " " + str(Year) + " , " + str(full_time)
```

At this point I thought about making the sum of the vars into like ASCII.

```
import pyfiglet 


result=pyfiglet.figlet_format(now, font = "digital") 
print(result)
```

Here I thought that a for loop might resolve the looping , so though comparing it with infinity

```
import math 
nr = math .inf 

if nr  >1000000000 : 
    print("This number is indeed infinite ")
```

And this is the big problem , the for loop that doesn't work at all

```
for int(result) in range(1,nr) 
print(result)
```

Comment: See https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Comment: You should go through a Python tutorial, do some exercises, then get back to your clock problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jarmod, I found that a `while` loop solved it!

```
import math 
nr = math .inf 

if nr  >1000000000 : 
    print("This number is indeed infinite ")

count = 0 
while count < nr :
  print(result)
```